# How to open Wordpress by server IP addres instead domain?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I'm trying to install Wordpress via Nginx.
I want to open Wordpress by accessing public IP address.

I extracted Wordpress to ~/wordpress

```
ls ~/wordpress/
index.php    readme.html      wp-admin            wp-comments-post.php  wp-content   wp-includes        wp-load.php   wp-mail.php      wp-signup.php     xmlrpc.php
license.txt  wp-activate.php  wp-blog-header.php  wp-config-sample.php  wp-cron.php  wp-links-opml.php  wp-login.php  wp-settings.php  wp-trackback.php
```

How should I change my Nginx conf?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name ?;

    client_max_body_size 500M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the full path to your `~/wordpress`.

Comment: @AlexD
/root/wordpress/

Comment: Your `nginx` `root` directive points to `/var/www/html/wordpress`.

Comment: In most Linux distributions, `nginx` cannot access `/root`.

Comment: @Paul so the most correct way is reinstall all server configuration via non root user?

Comment: Just put the WordPress directory somewhere `nginx` can access, such as the already configured `/var/www/html`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "listen" directive like this:

> listen 80 default_server;

It will make this virtual host the default server for handling the requests when their HTTP Host header remains unmatched with any other server blocks. Therefore, it should handle any access made directly through public IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

In nginx, `server_name: _`

Note that the admin pages require HTTPS by default which you can't do without a name (you can use any certificate as long as you don't mind clicking through the errors).

Although the core Wordpress should work (but you can't have it accessible both by address and name) a lot of plugins might not behave correctly.